# How can I grant contribute-like permissions to a document set without allowing the set to be deleted?

Tags: permissions, document

Is it possible to grant contribute-like permissions (even if I have to create a new permission level), to a document set without allowing the users to delete the document set itself?

I've got lots of end users who need to add/edit/delete documents within a document set.  How can I grant this permission without also allowing them to delete the document set itself?  I'd be restoring document sets from the recycle bin all the time!

When I create a new permission level, it seems I can only remove the ability to delete the document set by removing the "Use Remote Interfaces" permission.  Unfortunately, removing that also removes the ability to delete documents within the document set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an idea, definitely not a definite answer, but more of a workaround. You could give them the Contribute Permissive Level without the delete permission, like you said. But also, write a very small SPD workflow that is attached to the "Document" Content Type. This workflow can even be added as a custom action to the ECB menu that allows them to delete a document in the document set. The workflow would be an impersonated step of a higher permissive account that would just delete the document.

Comment: Your idea sounds like a good one.  I'll try it out on Tuesday and let you know how it worked out.